# Finding a specific element in nested Array MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, nosql, fastapi

## DB Schema

```
[{
  "_id": 1,
  "name": "city1",
  "districts": [
    {
      "id": 5,
      "name": "district 1",
      "neighborhoods": [
        {
          "id": 309,
          "name": "neighborhood 1"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 6,
      "name": "district 2",
      "neighborhoods": [
        {
          "id": 52280,
          "name": "neighborhood 2"
        }
      ]
    }
},
{
  "_id": 1,
  "name": "city2",
  "districts": [
    {
      "id": 5,
      "name": "district 3",
      "neighborhoods": [
        {
          "id": 309,
          "name": "neighborhood 3"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 6,
      "name": "district 4",
      "neighborhoods": [
        {
          "id": 52280,
          "name": "neighborhood 4"
        },
        {
          "id": 52287,
          "name": "neighborhood 5"
        }
      ]
    }
}]
```

## Goal

I would like to be able to check whether a 3-tuple combination is valid. Given some values for *name*, *districts.name*, and *district.neighborhoods.name*; I would like to check if those 3 values do indeed represent a valid combination. By *valid* I mean that they are nested in each other.

### Example 1

If I am given `city1`, `district 1`, and `neighborhood 1` as input, this is a valid combination (Because they are nested inside each other)

### Example 2

If I am given `city2`, `district 4`, and `neighborhood 4` as input, this is a valid combination

### Example 3

If I am given `city1`, `district 1`, and `neighborhood 2` as input, this is **NOT** a valid combination (because they are not nested inside each other)

### Example 4

If I am given `city1`, `district 3`, and `neighborhood 3` as input, this is **NOT** a valid combination

## Expected Output

Assuming I am given `city1`, `district 1`, and `neighborhood 1` (a valid combination) for *name*, *districts.name*, and *districts.neighborhoods.name* respectively. The output should be:

```
{
  "_id": 1,
  "name": "city1",
  "districts": [
    {
      "id": 5,
      "name": "district 1",
      "neighborhoods": [
        {
          "id": 309,
          "name": "neighborhood 1"
        }
      ]
    }
}
```

Assuming I am given `city1`, `district 1`, and `neighborhood 2` (**NOT** a valid combination) for *name*, *districts.name*, and *districts.neighborhoods.name* respectively. The output should be empty or null or something indicating that an array element with these values does not exist.

## Current Approach

```
doesLocationExist = await locationDbConnection.find_one(
        { "location" : {
            "$elemMatch" :  
                {"name" : city, "districts.name" : district, "districts.neighborhoods.name": neighborhood}
            }
        }
    )
```

I was hoping this would return a document if the combination is valid, but it always returns `None` even when the combination is valid.
Essentially what I am trying to do is retrieve a double-nested array element using the "path" (the 3-tuple input mentioned earlier); if that element exists, that means it is a valid combination, otherwise, it is not.

## Previous Questions That Did Not Help

- [Finding nested array mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29631420/finding-nested-array-mongodb)
- [Extracting particular element in MongoDb in Nested Arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42176046/extracting-particular-element-in-mongodb-in-nested-arrays)
- [Find document with array that contains a specific value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18148166/find-document-with-array-that-contains-a-specific-value)

P.S: the neighborhood and district names are not unique, so I cannot use projection to display only the array element of interest

Comment: What is the output you are expecting? Can you edit your posted question?

Comment: Also, the sample you have shared is an invalid JSON, kindly update the correct one.

Comment: @KayvanShah I added expected output and fixed the JSON

Comment: aggregation pipeiline with 2 unwinds

Comment: can there be situations that the district array and neighborhood array can have more than 1 in final

Comment: @cmgchess, is there not a more efficient way than unwinding everything? Because my arrays are 1000s of elements. And no, the final document is always a unique city-district-neighborhood combination

Comment: 2 unwinds and a match should the job easily then. the problem without unwinding is that you get the unwanted elements in district and neighbour arrays

Comment: @cmgchess I don't need the output, so to speak, but I only need to know whether the city-district-neighborhood combination is valid. In other words, I want to know whether the provided district exists in the provided city, and the provided neighborhood exists in the provided district.

Comment: how about a nested elemMatch. this however will give the whole record if the correct match occurs but still you can get if the combination exists if there is a result

Comment: @Ahmet-Salman can you give a check what i wrote below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A nested `$elemMatch` to check if the given combination exists. It will give a result if it does.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      name: city,
      districts: {
        $elemMatch: {
          name: district,
          neighborhoods: {
            $elemMatch: {
              name: neighborhood
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Chd0kGm01U8)

if you actually want the correct result you can keep doing `$match`,`$unwind` until you get the result. This is assuming if there is only 1 unique combination of city,district and neighborhood

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $match: { name: city } },
  { $unwind: "$districts" },
  { $match: { "districts.name": district } },
  { $unwind: "$districts.neighborhoods" },
  { $match: { "districts.neighborhoods.name": neighborhood } }
])
```

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/couGSv8D_AU)

if there is more than 1 unique combination a more complex grouping will be needed
[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/OTsB2j8ZOTv)